# Edge detection using TangoSupport_findEdgesNearPoint (C API) failed

Tags: google-project-tango

Recently, new updates with google tango mira provide us an interesting edge detection function in the support lib, i.e. TangoSupport_findEdgesNearPoint. 
From the description in the references:

```
TangoErrorType TangoSupport_findEdgesNearPoint(
  const TangoXYZij *point_cloud,
  const TangoImageBuffer *image_buffer,
  const TangoCameraIntrinsics *camera_intrinsics,
  const float uv_coordinates,
  TangoSupportEdge **edges,
  int *number_of_edges
)
```

I assume TangoSupportEdge **edges and int *number_of_edges serve two outputs and the rest as inputs. I used managers provided in support lib to update point_cloud, and image_buffer, and checked out it's working fine. The camera_intrinsics is initialized properly also. Following that, I declare and initialize the outputs (tried different size):

```
TangoSupportEdge** tangoEdgeArray_;
int tangoEdgeArraySize_;
tangoEdgeArraySize_ = 1;
tangoEdgeArray_ = new TangoSupportEdge* [1];
```

Then, I called the function:

```
int ret = TangoSupport_findEdgesNearPoint(front_cloud_, image_buffer_,
                                            &color_camera_intrinsics_, uvCoordTemp,
                                            tangoEdgeArray_, &tangoEdgeArraySize_);
```

And onTouchDown, I update uvCoordTemp and call this TangoSupport_findEdgesNearPoint. It kept throwing out this error and crashing whenever I touch the screen and trying to find some edge(s). Without access to the source code, I am confused what caused this opencv assertion failure.

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&), file /home/ubuntu/jobs/redwood_internal/RedwoodInternal/Redwood/3rdparty/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000049d2 (code=-6), thread 18928 (GLThread 1092)
```

If anybody are playing with the edge detection function, I would love to discuss with you here while exploring myself.

Comment: One thing worth to check is wether you buffers are still valid while calling this function. Note that the buffer you get from callback will be invalidated after the callback scope is over. In order to keep them, you have to memcpy then out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will run some trials and see. @JasonGuo .